# Java array out not showing

Tags: java, arrays

**Following java programs gives me this outcome like [I@4554617c**

```
public class Firstlast6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int testnums[] = {6,1,5,3};
        firstLast6(testnums);

        System.out.println(testnums);
    }

    public static boolean firstLast6(int[] nums){
        if (nums[0] == 6){
            return true;
        }else if (nums[nums.length-1] == 6){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use `Arrays.toString` method

Comment: testnums is a pointer, so its not going to print what you expect.

Comment: Thank you, it is working

Answer (score 0):

Yes, arrays do not have nice formatted `toString()` method...

Try `Arrays.toString(testnums)` instead...